# Does the Dragon Ball manga continue after Akira Toriyama's death?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

As far as I know, the one who made the Dragon Ball manga was artist Toyotaro with guidelines from Akira Toriyama. Probably the general ideas were set by Akira Toriyama and the general script and drawing by Toyotaro. So, what happens now? Does the manga continue with Toyotaro, or will it stop permanently or temporarily, have they announced something?

Comment: Lead time probably ensures some more issues.  First the ideas had to get to the artist, then the finished work had to be bound up and then released.  So there can be a few more issues without its continuing after the ideas are used up.

Comment: There has not been an official announcement so it's officially unknown. But discontinuation is unlikely for commercial reasons.

Comment: @sundowner I've just read it will enter hiatus. Not sure how reliable the source is

Comment: [Official site](https://dragon-ball-official.com/news/) does not say anything.

Comment: @sundowner I dont know which is his source, but this spanish speaking youtuber with 1.78 million followers claims it's official https://www.youtube.com/@yisustv